# How to increase page loading speed with AddThis widget?

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, addthis

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js"></script>
```

I am using this code for facebook, twitter etc, but there is a script in this which makes the page loading speed extremely slow. Can you please help with the solution for this, the entire code is below

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var addthis_config = {
        "data_track_addressbar": true
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4dfeea6f5bf22ac6">
</script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Comment: You should ask them to make it faster :) A solution would be to load them async

Comment: One obvious thing to do would be to move the javascript to the bottom of your page, right before `</body>`. Oh and I think you mean increase, not decrease ;-)

Comment: as u told i moved the script to the bottom of the page but no use

Comment: Hey, great - I just found their OPT-OUT page :)

Comment: Try installing Chrome or use Firefox with firebug. Then look in hte NET tab to see what took so long

Comment: If you want to decrease the page loading speed, add some gibberish unnecessary big files at head section. Use big big images. It should slow down your page loading speed.

Answer (score 5):

Besides moving everything to the bottom of the page as Mudshark already said, you can also use the async addthis version:

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381221-optimizing-addthis-performance#.USyDXiVuPYo

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#async=1"></script> 

 function initAddThis(){
      addthis.init()
 }
 // After the DOM has loaded...
 initAddThis();
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the solutions would be to use *deferred JavaScript loading pattern* for AddThis library.

There are several nice JavaScript libraries helping you out with that problem. I personally use mostly [Modernizr.load](http://modernizr.com/docs/) (or [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/) by itself)

You can read more on that issue and improvement in [Improve Your Page Performance With Lazy Loading](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/improve_page_performance_with_lazy_loading/) article.

As a side note, I was able to improve page load by about 35% average in my past projects by using deferred JavaScript loading patter. I hope that will help.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious thing to do would be to move the javascript to the bottom of your page, right before `</body>` so that everything else can load before it.

Comment: Well you're at the mercy of a third party script - how slow or fast it loads is beyond your control. There's not much more you can do, besides @WoLph's suggestion to use async.

Answer (score 0):

put `async="async"` attribute to your `script` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4dfeea6f5bf22ac6" async="async">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to note:

- you really don't need to load addthis immediately, you can load it relatively late during page rendering process,
- addthis .js file is huge, currently around 118kb, minimized and gzipped (sic!),
- due to its size it will always take relatively a lot of time for browser to compile and process it, especially on mobile devices.

Using `async` attribute in the `script` tag might help, however browsers consider mostly network resources when they see the attribute. Browsers don't take into account what impact the script might have on CPU usage, page rendering tree etc. (in browsers defence there's no way for them to determine it). For example scripts that take a long time to execute might block rendering of first frame or other crucial early paints. Even if we ignore network resources (connection slot, bandwidth etc.) required to fetch the addthis .js file it still may turn out that the script has severe impact on page loading process.

Note that while the `async` attribute hints browser that the resource can be loaded asynchronously it says nothing about the script execution when it is finally retrieved. JS in browsers is mostly single threaded and once browser start to process the .js file it can't back out of it and it has to let it finish running.

On my computer, evaluating the script in Chrome takes ~130-140ms and it blocks `ParseHTML` event for that long. On less powerful mobile devices it may easily jump to 500ms.

Because addthis is so big it would be best give browsers a little help and defer .js file fetch until other, more important components of page are displayed.  You should use dedicated .js deferring library for this task to make sure that it is processed after `DOMContentLoaded` event and after other important resources are processed. I personally use Lab.js for this as it's small and does its job well.

Note also that there exists `defer` attribute that you can add to `script` tag, however specification clearly states that the script with `defer` tag present has to be processed **before** `DOMContentLoaded` event - so no wins here.